# redefining 2d array as a referenced copy of another 2d array C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to copy a 2d array in to another variable by reference to avoid unnecessary computation. I essentially have two 2d arrays, current_array and new_array, and I generate new_array from current_array then replace.

I am trying to program conways game of life using openmp, but I am having problems copying the new array to the old one. I have tried using *current_array=*new_array, &current_array=&new_array, ... and all other combinations.
I don't know much about C or pointers but the teacher insists we use C.

```
void NextArray(int const height, int const width, int const CurrentArray[height][width], int NewArray[height][width]){
  for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
      NewArray[i][j] = Newpoint(i,j, CurrentArray);
    }
  }
}


int main(){
  int CurrentArray[height][width];
  int NewArray[height][width];
  InitialArray=fopen("matrix.txt", "r");

  for(long long i = 0; i < height; ++i){
    for(long long j = 0; j < width; ++j){
      fscanf(InitialArray, "%d", &CurrentArray[i][j]);
    }
  }

  NextArray(height, width, CurrentArray, NewArray);
  CurrentArray = NewArray;
  return 0;
}
```

I expect CurrentArray to have the same information that results from the NextArray function, if you define NewPoint like this:

```
void NextArray(int const i, int const j, int const CurrentArray[height][width]){
  if (CurrentArray[i][j]){
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

height = 2, width = 2, and "matrix.txt" as a file with the following:

```
0 0
1 1
```

then CurrentArray should be

```
1 1
0 0
```

Comment: What's your question?  All I see is a statement about what you expect.  Are you seeing something different?  If so, what?

Comment: Instead of copying the arrays, why don't you just have a pair of pointers, one that points to the current grid, the other points to the new grid. When you start a new generation, just swap the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy an array to an array of identical type (identical dimensions and element type), use:

```
memcpy(NewArray, CurrentArray, sizeof NewArray);
```

To make a pointer that refers to another array, use:

```
int (*NewArray)[width] = CurrentArray;
```

This works because, when `CurrentArray` is used in most expressions, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Since it is an array of arrays, its first element is an array. That array has type `int [width]`, and a pointer to such an array has type `int (*)[width]`. So declaring `NewArray` to with `int (*NewArray)[width]` defines it to have the right type to be assigned (and act like) a pointer to the first element of `CurrentArray`.

Given your task, you probably want two separate arrays—you want to have both the old data and the new data available. Your title asks for a “referenced copy”, but you probably do not want a reference to the old array, because then you have only one set of data that is accessed through two different identifiers.

Comment: If I make two arrays, I would then need to copy one to the other, I don't want to go array by array, so I wanted to make a referenced copy, after that I planned on redefining the new_array to remove the old reference. and starting a new one.

Comment: Tried out both solutions, had a bit of problems with the pointers, but I suspect that problem is on my side. memcpy worked great, thanks!

Comment: @HectorOfTheRose: What do you expect to do with a referenced copy of the array that you could not do with the original?

Comment: I am programming Conways Game of Life, so I was going to iterate through generations and transition through referenced copies instead of storing or copying element by element.

Since we are going to parallelize this the efficiency is important. That's why I can't just iterate and replace after calculating each generation.

Comment: @HectorOfTheRose: That does not answer the question of what you expect to do with a referenced copy that you could not do with the original. A reference is merely a way of accessing the original. It is not a separate copy. If you change the array via a pointer to the original, you will change the original. If you want to have two copies, you must have two separate arrays. (You can refer to the arrays with pointers that you swap between generations, as Barmar suggested.)

Comment: Well if I kept the new generation in new_array I would either have to swap to inserting the new gen in current_array or make an indefinite amount of variables, and since I don't know how many generations I need to make the second option isn't a solution. The first solution just seems like a really odd fix. 

Even though it's not a separate copy from what I understand you can redefine the second variable and "cut" the connection between the two, making it a faster way to copy a large 2d matrix since you only have to rewrite the pointers and not the content of the arrays.